# How to add shortGridlines between Major ticks in Time Cartisian Axis in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js@4.2.1 and chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0. I want to have 9 shortgridlines between
each two major ticks in Time Cartisian Axis in both axis. I am able to see the the gridline on major ticks with label but also need  to have gridlines on minor tick without labels.

currently my code:

```
scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'time',
          time: {
              displayFormats: {
                month: 'dd MMM yy'
              },

              unit: 'day'
            },
            
            ticks: {
              color: "black",
                            
            },
           
            grid {
              DrawOnChartArea : false
            },
            
          },

        y: {
            type: 'linear',
            position:'left'
            ticks: {
              color: "black"
                   },
            grid:{
            display = false
                }
          },
          y1: {
            type: 'linear',           
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            ticks: {
              color: "black",
              
              },
            grid:{
            display = false
                }
            }
           }
          }
```